# How do I programmatically apply a coupon in Woocommerce by API?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Hi I'm looking to apply a coupon discount of 10% to the cart I've looked at the code from a previous user and tried modifying it and placing it in my file, however it doesn't work for me - Any help as to what I'm doing wrong?

Remember, I use this code for my APP API

Here is the code :

```
function create_wc_order($request) {

    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if (!$user->ID) {
        // exit if user not logged in
        return;
    }

    $order = wc_create_order(array('customer_id' => $user->ID, 'customer_ip' => WC_Geolocation::get_ip_address()));

    foreach ($request['products'] as $prd) {
        $order->add_product( get_product( (int)$prd['id'] ), (int)$prd['qty']);
    }

    // set order address
    $order->set_address( $request['billing'], 'billing' );

    if ($request['shipping_as_billing'] == 'true') {
        $order->set_address( $request['billing'], 'shipping' );
    } else {
        $order->set_address( $request['shipping'], 'shipping' );
    }

    // set payment gateway
    $payment_gateways = WC()->payment_gateways->payment_gateways();
    if ($request['payment_gateway'] == 'cod' || $request['payment_gateway'] == 'bacs' || $request['payment_gateway'] == 'payfort') {
        $order->set_payment_method( $payment_gateways[$request['payment_gateway']] );
    } elseif ($request['payment_gateway'] == 'sadad') {
        //$order->set_payment_method( 'payfort' );
        update_post_meta($order->id, '_payment_method_title', __('SADAD', 'payfort_fort'));
        update_post_meta($order->id, '_payment_method', PAYFORT_FORT_PAYMENT_METHOD_SADAD);
    } elseif ($request['payment_gateway'] == 'installments') {
        //$order->set_payment_method( 'payfort' );
        update_post_meta($order->id, '_payment_method_title', __('INSTALLMENTS', 'payfort_fort'));
        update_post_meta($order->id, '_payment_method', PAYFORT_FORT_PAYMENT_METHOD_INSTALLMENTS);
    }


     $coupon_code = 'UNIQUECODE';
     $order->add_coupon($coupon_code);

     if (isset($coupon_code)) {
         if ( ! WC()->cart->has_discount( $coupon_code ) ) {
             WC()->cart->add_discount( $coupon_code );
        }
    }

    $order->calculate_totals();
    $order->update_status( 'Pending', 'Order created by API - ', true);

    return $order->get_data();
}
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'wp/v2', '/create_order/', array(
    'methods' => 'POST',
    'callback' => 'create_wc_order',
  ) );
} );
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Woocommerce - create new order using wc\_create\_order but discounts not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32914575/woocommerce-create-new-order-using-wc-create-order-but-discounts-not-working)

Comment: @AlexTartan i try this post but not work with me !